# MvcMusicStore v3.0 Tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I can not go through this tutorial because:

1 - Despite installing SP1 for visual studio, my dialogs are different than in tutorial. For example there is no "HTML5" option in "Add View" dialog.
2 - DbSet is not in Entity Framework and
3 - EntityFramework does not show up in NuGet list.

Anybody had a successful go through with this tutorial?

Note: That's a sad situation for a tutorial to be this hard to start (especially for MVC which I am getting interested in).

Note: I have not looked into NerdDinner. I hope that one goes better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mentioned prerequisites in [first part](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1):

> •ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3

Did you get this one? This update is the thing that will give you new options in MVC dialogs. Then also the entity framework should be update, because when you create new MVC3 app after this update, you will get automatically few packages in it (and newest version of EF is there).

Comment: Thankyou! I will read that part again. But as mentioned I can not seen the EntityFramework NuGet in the list of online packages.

Comment: And I have installed VS 2010 SP1!

Comment: Dunno why you don't see it. I would be only guessing with current informations. You might need to update your NuGet. Also depends on what exactly are you looking for at nuget. Check the official site with packages too... www.nuget.org

Comment: Thanks @Dampe! I have looked into www.nuget.org and it's name is EntityFramework. But does not show up in search :(

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian: Weird... you can try using Package Manager Console (View - Other Windows). And type following command `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 2010 Premium with SP1, and just recently completed the MVC 3 Music Store tutorial: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379 . I am a new-ish developer and found it very easy to follow, did not notice issues with dialogs, and I learned a lot. After completing it I started nerd dinner, which I find not as easy a read. I also found this usefull: http://tekpub.com/production/starter